# Notifications won't open file

Tags: java, android

I am tring to open an uploaded file through notifications, but it is not working, the notification appears but once I click on it, nothing happens.

This is the notification part of my code :

```
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

Intent i = new Intent();      
i.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+file_path), f.getString("type") );
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Main.this, 0,  i , 0); 

mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( BabupMain.this);
mBuilder.setContentTitle("test").addAction(android.R.drawable.alert_dark_frame, "hi",contentIntent) 
                                .setContentText("click to open the file")
                                .setLights(0xfff89829, 300, 5000)
                                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                                .setSound(uri)
                                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);


mNotifyManager.notify( NOTIFICATION_ID , mBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used NotificationCompat, so don't know if it does this,
but I created an Intent and then had to use

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

to tie the intent of opening your file with the notification

Comment: i used your code but still can't open the file from notification , i need to open the file once i click on the notification

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Intent the way you did *may* start an app that can view files, but if no app matches your Intent, nothing will happen.

You have this mysterious piece of code

{i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+file_path), f.getString("type"))}

but no mention of what "f" is, so I can't tell if {f.getString("type")) results in a valid
MIME type.

All this is moot anyway. A notification's content Intent should, in nearly all cases, go back to the app that created the notification. Doing this provides the best context to the user. *From the application*, allow the user to send another Intent to open the file.

Remember also to set the back stack correctly. The current implementation doesn't do this, so it results in a confusing navigation path once the the file is viewed.